# How to set and get multimethod docstring in clojure?

Tags: clojure, docstring, multimethod

I'm using multimethods to parse command line commands and their arguments.

```
(defmulti run (fn [command args] command))

(defmethod run :default
  [& _]
  ...)

^{:args "[command]"}
(defmethod run "help"
  [_ & [args]]
  "Display command list or help for a given command"
  ...)

^{:args ""}
(defmethod run "version"
  [_ & [args]]
  "Print program's version"
  ...)

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (run (first args)
    (next args)))
```

When I try to access the docstring for a specific method, clojure raises an exception:

```
(doc ((methods run) "help"))
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.core/find-ns (core.clj:3996)
```

Is it possible to set a docstring on a specific method and get it in the code later?

Comment: Since docstring itself is placed in metadata, I'd consider this as duplicate.

Comment: @OlegTheCat Well, in that case it's better to mark the question as duplicate.